# What is the difference between include and extend in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, module, include, extend

Just getting my head around Ruby metaprogramming. The mixin/modules always manage to confuse me.

- **include**: mixes in specified module methods as **instance methods** in the target class
- **extend**: mixes in specified module methods as **class methods** in the target class

*So is the major difference just this or is a bigger dragon lurking?*
e.g.

```
module ReusableModule
  def module_method
    puts "Module Method: Hi there!"
  end
end

class ClassThatIncludes
  include ReusableModule
end
class ClassThatExtends
  extend ReusableModule
end

puts "Include"
ClassThatIncludes.new.module_method       # "Module Method: Hi there!"
puts "Extend"
ClassThatExtends.module_method            # "Module Method: Hi there!"
```

Comment: Check this link out too: http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/15/mixins-in-ruby/

Answer (score 284, accepted):

What you have said is correct. However, there is more to it than that.

If you have a class `Klazz` and module `Mod`, including `Mod` in `Klazz` gives instances of `Klazz` access to `Mod`'s methods. Or you can extend `Klazz` with `Mod` giving the *class* `Klazz` access to `Mod`'s methods. But you can also extend an arbitrary object with `o.extend Mod`. In this case the individual object gets `Mod`'s methods even though all other objects with the same class as `o` do not.

Comment: terse like Confucius.

Answer (score 401):

**extend** - adds the specified module's methods and constants to the target's metaclass (i.e. the singleton class) 
  e.g.

- if you call `Klazz.extend(Mod)`, now Klazz has Mod's methods (as class methods)
- if you call `obj.extend(Mod)`, now obj has Mod's methods (as instance methods), but no other instance of of `obj.class` has those methods added.
- `extend` is a public method

**include** - By default, it mixes in the specified module's methods as instance methods in the target module/class. 
  e.g.

- if you call `class Klazz; include Mod; end;`, now all instances of Klazz have access to Mod's methods (as instance methods)
- `include` is a private method, because it's intended to be called from within the container class/module.

**However**, modules very often *override* `include`'s behavior by monkey-patching the `included` method. This is very prominent in legacy Rails code. [more details from Yehuda Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/12/better-ruby-idioms/).

Further details about `include`, with its default behavior, assuming you've run the following code

```
class Klazz
  include Mod
end
```

- If Mod is already included in Klazz, or one of its ancestors, the include statement has no effect
- It also includes Mod's constants in Klazz, as long as they don't clash
- It gives Klazz access to Mod's module variables, e.g. `@@foo` or `@@bar`
- raises ArgumentError if there are cyclic includes
- Attaches the module as the caller's immediate ancestor (i.e. It adds Mod to Klazz.ancestors, but Mod is not added to the chain of Klazz.superclass.superclass.superclass. So, calling `super` in Klazz#foo will check for Mod#foo before checking to Klazz's real superclass's foo method. See the RubySpec for details.).

Of course, [the ruby core documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/) is always the best place to go for these things. [The RubySpec project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubySpec) was also a fantastic resource, because they documented the functionality precisely.

- `#include` [RubySpec](https://github.com/ruby/rubyspec/blob/master/core/module/include_spec.rb) [rubydoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-include)
- `#included` [RubySpec](https://github.com/ruby/rubyspec/blob/master/core/module/included_spec.rb) [rubydoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-included)
- `#extend` [RubySpec](https://github.com/ruby/rubyspec/blob/master/core/kernel/extend_spec.rb) [rubydoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-extend)
- `#extended` [RubySpec](https://github.com/ruby/rubyspec/blob/master/core/module/extended_spec.rb) [rubydoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-extended)
- `#extend_object` [RubySpec](https://github.com/ruby/rubyspec/blob/master/core/module/extend_object_spec.rb) [rubydoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-extend_object)
- `#append_features` [RubySpec](https://github.com/ruby/rubyspec/blob/master/core/module/append_features_spec.rb) [rubydoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-append_features)

Comment: I know this is pretty old post, but the clarity of the reply couldn't hold me back from commenting. Thanks a lot for a nice explanation.

Comment: @anwar Obviously, but now I can comment and I managed to find the article again. It is available here : http://aaronlasseigne.com/2012/01/17/explaining-include-and-extend/  and I still think the schema make the understanding much easier

Comment: The big win in this response is how `extend` can apply methods as class *or* instance methods, depending on utilization. `Klass.extend` = class methods, `objekt.extend` = instance methods. I always (wrongly) assumed class methods came from `extend`, and instance from `include`.

Comment: Everything as said above, just one nit detail: `extend` does include a module on the inheritance chain of the singleton class (for more details on this see [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/611847-ruby-extend-extends-the-singleton-class-s-inheritance-chain)) Also as display within the article in the comment of @systho

Answer (score 17):

That's correct.

Behind the scenes, include is actually an alias for **append_features**, which (from the docs):

> Ruby's default implementation is to
>   add the constants, methods, and module
>   variables of this module to aModule if
>   this module has not already been added
>   to aModule or one of its ancestors.

Answer (score 14):

When you **`include`** a module into a class, the module methods are imported as **instance methods**.

However, when you **`extend`** a module into a class, the module methods are imported as **class methods**.

For example, if we have a module `Module_test` defined as follows:

```
module Module_test
  def func
    puts "M - in module"
  end
end
```

Now, for **`include`** module. If we define the class `A` as follows:

```
class A
  include Module_test
end

a = A.new
a.func
```

The output will be: `M - in module`.

If we replace the line `include Module_test` with `extend Module_test` and run the code again, we receive the following error: `undefined method 'func' for #<A:instance_num> (NoMethodError)`.

Changing the method call `a.func` to `A.func`, the output changes to: `M - in module`.

From the above code execution, it is clear that when we **`include`** a module, its methods become **instance methods** and when we **`extend`** a module, its methods become **class methods**.

Comment: the instance methods are included as instance methods, while module methods are not... from https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Module.html

Answer (score 3):

All the other answers are good, including the tip to dig through RubySpecs:

https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/core/module/include_spec.rb

https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/core/module/extend_object_spec.rb

As for use cases:

If you *include* module ReusableModule in class ClassThatIncludes, the methods, constants, classes, submodules, and other declarations gets referenced.

If you *extend* class ClassThatExtends with module ReusableModule, then the methods and constants gets *copied*. Obviously, if you are not careful, you can waste a lot of memory by dynamically duplicating definitions.

If you use ActiveSupport::Concern, the .included() functionality lets you rewrite the including class directly. module ClassMethods inside a Concern gets *extended* (copied) into the including class.

Answer (score 3):

I would also like to explain the mechanism as it works. If I am not right please correct.

When we use `include` we are adding a linkage from our class to a module which contains some methods.

```
class A
include MyMOd
end

a = A.new
a.some_method
```

Objects don't have methods, only clases and modules do.
So when `a` receives mesage `some_method` it begin search method `some_method` in `a`'s eigen class, then in `A` class and then in linked to `A` class modules if there are some (in reverse order, last included wins).

When we use `extend` we are adding linkage to a module in object's eigen class.
So if we use A.new.extend(MyMod) we are adding linkage to our module to A's instance eigen class or `a'` class.
And if we use A.extend(MyMod) we are adding linkage to A(object's, classes are also objects) eigenclass `A'`.

so method lookup path for `a` is as follows:
a => a' => linked modules to a' class => A.

also there is a prepend method which changes lookup path:

a => a' => prepended modulesto A => A => included module to A

sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3):

I came across a very useful [article](https://dev.to/abbiecoghlan/ruby-modules-include-vs-extend-vs-prepend-4gmc) that compares `include`, `extend` and `prepend` methods used **inside a class**:

`include` adds module methods as instance methods to the class, whereas `extend` adds module methods as class methods. The module being included or extended must be defined accordingly

Answer (score 0):

**include** provides a class with access to a module's methods as an instance

```
methods
module Plant
  def poisonous?
    true
  end
end

class PlantKingdom
end

class Hemlock < PlantKingdom
  include Plant
end

obj = Hemlock.new()

obj.poisonous?
=> true

Hemlock.poisonous?
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `poisonous?' for Hemlock:Class
```

**extend** provides a class with access to a module's methods as class methods

```
module Plant
  def poisonous?
    true
  end
end

class PlantKingdom
end

class Hemlock < PlantKingdom
  extend Plant
end

obj = Hemlock.new()

obj.poisonous?
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `poisonous?' for #<Hemlock:0x00007fa84389c748>

Hemlock.poisonous?
=> true
```