# Extending classes and instances

Tags: ruby, extension-methods

This question has two parts.

In the Ruby Programming Language book, there is an example (section 8.1.1) of extending a string object and class with a module.

First question. Why is it that if you extend a class with a new method, and then create an object/instance of that class, you cannot access that method?

```
irb(main):001:0> module Greeter; def ciao; "Ciao!"; end; end
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> String.extend(Greeter)
=> String
irb(main):003:0> String.ciao
=> "Ciao!"
irb(main):004:0> x = "foo bar"
=> "foo bar"
irb(main):005:0> x.ciao
NoMethodError: undefined method `ciao' for "foo bar":String
        from (irb):5
        from :0
irb(main):006:0>
```

Second part, When I try to extend a Fixnum object, I get an undefined method error. Can someone explain why this works for a string but not a fixnum?

```
irb(main):045:0> module Greeter; def ciao; "Ciao!"; end; end
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> 3.extend(Greeter)
TypeError: can't define singleton
        from (irb):6:in `extend_object'
        from (irb):6:in `extend'
        from (irb):6
```

Answer (score 10):

> First question. Why is it that if you
>   extend a class with a new method, and
>   then create an object/instance of that
>   class, you cannot access that method?

Because you extended the String class, so #ciao is a class method and not an instance method.

```
String.send(:include, Greeter)
x = "foo bar"
x.ciao
# => "Ciao!"
```

> Second part, When I try to extend a
>   Fixnum object, I get an undefined
>   method error. Can someone explain why
>   this works for a string but not a
>   fixnum?

Here's the [short answer](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/50170#16763).

> "Fixnums, Symbols, true, nil, and
>   false are implemented as immediate
>   values. With immediate values,
>   variables hold the objects themselves,
>   rather than references to them.
>
> Singleton methods cannot be defined
>   for such objects. Two Fixnums of the
>   same value always represent the same
>   object instance, so (for example)
>   instance variables for the Fixnum with
>   the value "one" are shared between all
>   the "ones" is the system. This makes
>   it impossible to define a singleton
>   method for just one of these."

Off course, you can include/exten the Fixnum class and every Fixnum instance will expose the methods in the Mixin.
This is exactly what Rails/ActiveSupport does in order to allow you to write

```
3.days.ago
1.hour.from_now
```

Comment: Your answer to the first part doesn't explain (to me) the why. In other languages, when you change the class, and create a new object of that class type, you get the new method. I am making an assumption that there is a connection from class to objects that is invalid. Can you explain why that connection is not valid here?

Comment: Researching the "include" you gave me helped. So, it looks like now that I understand there exists a difference between extend and include, and now know what to search for, there is a post here that explains those differences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156362/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-ruby

Answer (score 2):

`obj.extend(module)` adds all the methods in `module` to `obj`. When called as `String.extend(Greeter)` you are adding the methods from `Greeter` to the instance of `Class` that represents `String`.

The easiest way to add additional instance methods to an existing class is to re-open the class. The following examples do the same thing:

```
class String
  include Greeter
end

class String
  def ciao
    "Ciao!"
  end
end
```

Fixnums (as well as Symbols, true, false and nil) are handled in a different way to normal instances. Two Fixnums with the same value will always be represented by the same object instance. As a result, Ruby doesn't allow you to extend them.

You can of course extend an instance of any other class, e.g.:

```
t = "Test"
t.extend(Greeter)
t.ciao
=> "Ciao!"
```