# What is the difference between "include module" and "extend module" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, module, include, extend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between include and extend in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156362/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-ruby)

Given:

```
module my_module
  def foo
    ...
  end
end
```

**Question 1**

What is the difference between:

```
class A
  include my_module
end
```

and

```
class A
  extend my_module
end
```

**Question 2**

Will `foo` be considered an instance method or a class method ? 
In other words, is this equivalent to:

```
class A
  def foo
    ...
  end
end
```

or to:

```
class A
  def self.foo
    ...
  end
end
```

?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I wrote a blog posting about this a long time ago [here](http://mauricio.github.io/2008/09/27/including-and-extending-modules-in-ruby.html).

When you're "including" a module, the module is included as if the methods were defined at the class that's including them, you could say that it's copying the methods to the including class.

When you're "extending" a module, you're saying "add the methods of this module to **this specific instance**". When you're inside a class definition and say "extend" the "instance" is the class object itself, but you could also do something like this (as in my blog post above):

```
module MyModule
  def foo
    puts "foo called"
  end
end

class A
end

object = A.new
object.extend MyModule

object.foo #prints "foo called"
```

So, it's not exactly a class method, but a method to the "instance" which you called "extend". As you're doing it inside a class definition and the instance in there is the class itself, it "looks like" a class method.

Comment: It's actually the other way around... includes adds instance methods and extends adds class methods...why does this have 30 votes?

Comment: The question isn't referring to extending on a specific instance which is what you're doing with `object.extend MyModule` it's referring to extending in the body of the class in which the receiver (`self`) is the class itself, hence it's adding class methods.

Answer (score 20):

1) `include` adds methods, constants, and variables on instances of class `A`; `extend` adds those things to the instance of the `Class` instance `A` (effectively defining class methods).

`include my_module` will allow this: `A.new.foo`

`extend my_module` will allow this: `A.foo`

More generally, `include` only makes sense on a `Class` or `Module`, while `extend` can be used to add methods to any `Object`.

2) In effect: when using `include`, `foo` is an instance method of `A` ... when using `extend`, `foo` is a class method.