# Ruby - "extend" statement in a class

Tags: ruby

If (for whatever reason) I `extend Stuff` in `class Dog` how can I access `CONST1` through the Dog class?  I know I can get CONST1 by saying `Stuff::CONST1`, but how through dog can I get it. I also know that this code would work if I `include Stuff` in `class Dog`.

```
module Stuff 
  CONST1 = "Roll Over"
end

class Dog 
  extend Stuff  
end


Dog::CONST1 #NameError: uninitialized constant Dog::CONST1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably thinking of `include`, not `extend`.

[`extend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-extend) adds the instance methods:

> Adds to *obj* the instance methods from each module given as a parameter.

but [`include`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-include):

> Invokes `Module.append_features` on each parameter in reverse order.

and [`append_features`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-append_features):

> Ruby‘s default implementation is to add the **constants**, methods, and module variables of this module to *mod* if this module has not already been added to *mod* or one of its ancestors.

So if you do this:

```
module M
  PANCAKES = 11
end

class C
  include M
end
```

Then you can get `PANCAKES` from `C`:

```
puts C::PANCAKES
# gives you 11
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation of extend](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001002):

> Adds to obj the instance methods from each module given as a parameter.

It seems there is no reason to expect `extend` to add the constants.

Comment: It just seems odd that I might have a useful module ... and want its methods available as class methods for a class I have defined ... yet I cannot access the modules constants.  The only way to access the constants is to include it, but I want the methods to be class methods... how can I do this?

Comment: `...but I want the methods to be class methods...` what do you mean by this? The methods you add to `Stuff` WILL be available as class methods to `Dog` if you extend. On your example, creating a method called `test` on `Stuff` will allow you to do `Dog.test`.

Comment: Yes, by using `extend Stuff`the methods defined in the module Stuff will be class methods to Dog.  What I am asking is... I would like to be able to be able use a modules methods as class methods on a given class. To accomplish this you use `extend` not `include` as `include` will make the methods instance methods.  But what if there are CONSTANTS in that module that I am extending? It seems logical that I may need to access those CONSTANTS. The only way to access them is to `include` them.... but I don't want instance methods... I want class methods. Is it possible to access them?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
module Stuff
  CONST1 = "Roll Over"
end

class Dog 
  include Stuff  
end


Dog::CONST1 # works
```

See [What is the difference between include and extend in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156362/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-ruby)