# Ruby mixin: extend or include?

Tags: ruby, singleton, metaclass, mixins

I have following code:

```
module CarHelper
  def call_helpline
    puts "Calling helpline..."
  end
end

class Car
  extend CarHelper
end

class Truck
  class << self
    include CarHelper
  end
end

# Test code
Car.call_helpline
Truck.call_helpline
```

In fact both 2 lines of test codes works. So is there any difference
between the way I use '`extend`' and '`include`' (inside a singleton class
of `self`)?

Comment: See the interesting discussion about [What is the difference between include and extend in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156362/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No , It's the same thing but the first way is cleaner .