# Use one action for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I have about 5 models that behave very similarly. In fact, I'd like them to share an action for displaying them. For example, for models Car, Truck, Van I want to have a definition like:

```
[Car, Truck, Van].each do |Model|
  action_for Model do #I made this up to show what I mean
    def index
      @model = Model.all
      @model_names = @model.map(&:name).join(', ')
    end
  end
end
```

How would I do this so I'm not defining the same action in multiple controllers? (Which isn't very DRY) Would it be in the application_controller? And if it's not too much to ask, how could I do this so they also share the view?

**UPDATE**

It would be preferred if this can be outside the individual controllers. If I can get this to work right, I'd like to not even have to generate the individual controllers.

Comment: You might be interested in peeping or using [Inheritable Resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) by José Valim. ActiveAdmin uses it for default RESTful actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
module Display
  def index
    m = self.class.to_s.chomp('Controller').classify.constantize
    @model = m.all
    @model_names = @model.map(&:name).join(', ')
  end
end
```

In the controllers:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  include Display 
end

class TrucksController < ApplicationController
  include Display 
end

class VansController < ApplicationController
  include Display 
end
```

**Edit:** an attempt to do this without individual controllers

```
class DisplaysController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @model = params[:model].constantize.all
    @model_names = @model.map(&:name).join(', ')
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
match "display" => "display#index", :as => :display
```

In a view

```
link_to "Display Cars", display_path(:model => "Car")
link_to "Display Trucks", display_path(:model => "Truck")
link_to "Display Vans", display_path(:model => "Van")
```

Note: If you've heard of `extend` for modules and are wondering why/when to use `include` vs `extend`, see [What is the difference between include and extend in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156362/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-ruby) (basically include is for instances, extend for class methods).

Comment: Very good! I'm going to hold out for a bit though if you don't mind. If I can find the answer I'm thinking of, I shouldn't even need controllers for each of the models

Comment: @KyleMacey - I think my edit will work for you but I have not tested. Let me know if you try it and it doesn't work so I can remove it.

Comment: Rather than using `Object.const_get` you can use `constantize`. You can shorten that whole line up to `m = name.chomp('Controller').classify.constantize`.

Comment: I thought it might be useful to note when to use `include` vs. `extend` which people may well have heard of, so I added that at the bottom of this answer (above) as a note.

Comment: The code `self.class.to_s.chomp('Controller')` can be replaced with `controller_name`

Comment: I might have to go with your original method. I don't want to sacrifice clean routing on behalf of my own laziness. Having `/vans` and `/trucks` seems to make the most sense to me. Thanks for great answers!

Comment: @KyleMacey did you settle on a method? I'm curious.

Comment: @Kyle Ended up writing a custom generation file to regenerate and populate the controllers when I want to make changes. I couldn't get the Module to work right, and I need pretty routes. I'll post as an answer so you can see.