# Ruby inheritance and instances

Tags: ruby

I made a class `User` (which is an instance of `Class`), and made it inherit from class `Person`. What makes this considered not to be multiple inheritance? Doesn't it inherit instance methods like `new` from `Class` and any methods that `Person` offers?

In other words, how is this not multiple inheritance:

```
class User < class Person
  some methods here...
end
```

when `User` already inherits all of `Class`'s methods? Isn't the following what is going on under the hood?

```
class User < class Person and class Class
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Inheritance in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254689/multiple-inheritance-in-ruby)

Comment: Hey I edited my comment to be more specific.  That post is more about specifying literally two parent classes whereas my question is how can any class in ruby list another class as a parent when it's parent looks like class "Class"...

Comment: Your code is not valid Ruby syntax.  `User` is not a child of `Class`, it is an instance of `Class` class

Comment: "Multiple inheritance" as a feature of a language is something exposed to users of that language. This is not actually useful as multiple inheritance to users of Ruby; you cannot inherit from two arbitrary classes.

Comment: `new` is not an instance method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open irb you can check it yourself. Type `User.superclass`, you will see that `User` has only one superclass, which is `Person`. `User` will inherit the methods from `Object` because `Person`'s superclass is `Object`

Comment: Thank you that really clears things up!   What confused me is that I didn't realize everything fits nicely together in one big chain of command!  Even though User and Person are instances of the class "Class", if you do Class.superclass you get Module and if you take the superclass of that you are back to Object!  It all comes full circle!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not "multiple inheritance" in usual way, but a simple chain of inheritance.

Ancestors cannot have own constructors unless you call them explicitly from `initialize`, and in complex hierarchies this can be very painful.
The main point is that there's only one instance object, that is shared and methods are mixed into it.

In ruby class hierarchy is always a tree. Even mixins, that may look like a multiple inheritance - internally are implemented as inheritance chain.

True multiple inheritance can be hard, for example, in C++:

```
class A {}
class B: public A{}
class C: public A{}
class D: public B, public C{}
```

How many instances of `A` should be inside `D`? (the "diamond problem")

Ruby avoids it by simply not having the cause.