# Include vs extend within another module

Tags: ruby, module, include

Why does the code below return `NoMethodFound` error:

```
module Mod1
  def print_string
    puts 'hello ruby'
  end
end
module Mod2
  include Mod1
end
Mod2.print_string
```

while the code below runs fine?

```
module Mod1
  def print_string
    puts 'hello ruby'
  end
end
module Mod2
  extend Mod1
end
Mod2.print_string
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156362/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-ruby?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**extend** - adds the specified module's methods and constants to the target's metaclass (i.e. the singleton class) 
  e.g.

- if you call `Klazz.extend(Mod)`, now Klazz has Mod's methods (as class methods)
- if you call `obj.extend(Mod)`, now obj has Mod's methods (as instance methods), but no other instance of of `obj.class` has those methods.
- `extend` is a public method

**include** - By default, it mixes in the specified module's methods as instance methods in the target module/class. 
  e.g.

- if you call `class Klazz; include Mod; end;`, now all instances of Klazz have access to Mod's methods (as instance methods)
- `include` is a private method, because it's intended to be called from within the container class/module.

**However**, modules very often *override* `include`'s behavior by monkey-patching the `included` method. This is very prominent in legacy Rails code. [more details from Yehuda Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/12/better-ruby-idioms/).

Further details about `include`, with its default behavior, assuming you've run the following code

```
class Klazz
  include Mod
end
```

- If Mod is already included in Klazz, or one of its ancestors, the include statement has no effect
- It also includes Mod's constants in Klazz, as long as they don't clash
- It gives Klazz access to Mod's module variables, e.g. `@@foo` or `@@bar`
- raises ArgumentError if there are cyclic includes
- Attaches the module as the caller's immediate ancestor (i.e. It adds Mod to Klazz.ancestors, but Mod is not added to the chain of Klazz.superclass.superclass.superclass. So, calling `super` in Klazz#foo will check for Mod#foo before checking to Klazz's real superclass's foo method. See the RubySpec for details.).

Of course, [the ruby core documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/) is always the best place to go for these things. [The RubySpec project](http://www.rubyspec.org/) is also a fantastic resource, because they document the functionality precisely.

- ## include [RubySpec](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/core/module/include_spec.rb) [rubydoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-include)
- ## included [RubySpec](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/core/module/included_spec.rb) [rubydoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-included)
- ## extend [RubySpec](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/core/kernel/extend_spec.rb) [rubydoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-extend)
- ## extended [RubySpec](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/core/module/extended_spec.rb) [rubydoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-extended)
- ## extend_object [RubySpec](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/core/module/extend_object_spec.rb) [rubydoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-extend_object)
- ## append_features [RubySpec](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/core/module/append_features_spec.rb) [rubydoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-append_features)

ref: [John](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156362/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `extend` adds the module's methods as class methods to the caller, whereas `include` adds them as instance methods.

An example (using classes instead of modules since modules can't have instances...)

This works...

```
module Mod1
  def print_string
    puts 'hello ruby'
  end
end
class Mod2
  extend Mod1
end
Mod2.print_string
```

And this works...

```
module Mod1
  def print_string
    puts 'hello ruby'
  end
end
class Mod2
  include Mod1
end
mod_instance = Mod2.new
mod_instance.print_string
```