# How to extend a custom module in a custom ruby script under Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a ruby script `lib/tasks/material_parser_helper.rb`

and a module `lib/common_parser_methods.rb`

How could I extends all the module methods into 'material_parser_helper.rb'

Therefore, I can call the `clean_key` in any methods of **MaterialParserHelper**

If I tried to **extend CommonParserMethods** after the class,

I will got the error `NameError: uninitialized constant SummaryProjection::CommonMethods`

```
class MaterialParserHelper
  extend CommonParserMethods

  def   test
      clean_key("jckdj")
  end

end
```

## common_parser_methods.rb

```
module CommonParserMethods
  def clean_key(key)
    return key.strip.squish.gsub(/\s/, '_').gsub('-', '_').downcase
  end
end
```

## Application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/ #{config.root}/lib/common_parser_methods.rb #{config.root}/lib/tasks)
```

Comment: First of all your application.rb is wrong, the brackets are incomplete.

Comment: @Almaron Hi I didn't found where does the cinomeplete happens , I think the syntax is right, otherwise the Rails should give me error. https://github.com/shail85/fakesbook/blob/1ff72596de8cd3ec200570bde2077f2dfa314828/config/initializers/file

Comment: Your closing bracket is commented out. It should be `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/) #comment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to **include** CommonParserMethods, not **extend** your class with it. This will give instances of MaterialParserHelper the methods defined in CommonParserMethods.

More info on include vs. extend here: [What is the difference between include and extend in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/156362/597358)

That said, your error message references some code that is not shown; a class called `SummaryProjection`. Are you sure that the MaterialParserMethods class is causing this problem?