# Ruby: modules extending/including modules

Tags: ruby, module, extend

I'm trying to better understand how modules extend and include each other.

Say I have module **A**:

```
module A
  def learned_from_A
    true
  end
end

A.instance_methods  # [:learned_from_A]
```

I mix its bag of tricks into **B**:

```
module B
  extend A
end

B.learned_from_A  # true
```

I naively attempt to give **C** everything **B** has:

```
module C
  extend B
end

C.learned_from_A  # NoMethodError
```

I think I've wrapped my head around this. When **B** extends **A**, copies of A's instance methods are bound to **B** via B's singleton class:

```
B.singleton_methods  # [:learned_from_A]
```

While *:learned_from_A* is callable on **B**, it's not one of **B**'s *instance* methods, so when **C** extends **B**, *:learned_from_A* is *not* copied to **C**.

---

If **B** had instead *included* **A**, copies of A's instance methods would've been included among B's own instance methods.

```
module B
  include A
end

B.instance_methods  # [:learned_from_A]
```

Then, **C** could extend **B**, and all of B's instance methods (including *:learned_from_A*) would be copied and bound to **C**.

```
module C
  extend B
end

C.singleton_methods  # [:learned_from_A]
```

To make *:learned_from_A* callable on both **B** *and* **C**, **B** could extend *and* include **A**.

```
module B
  include A
  extend A
end

B.instance_methods   # [:learned_from_A]
B.singleton_methods  # [:learned_from_A]

module C
  extend B
end

C.instance_methods   # []
C.singleton_methods  # [:learned_from_A]
```

---

More realistically, if I want **A**'s methods to be callable on **B**, and for **B** to define another method of its own, *and* be able to mix the whole repertoire into **C**, I can't do this:

```
module B
  extend A
  include A

  def self.buzz
    true
  end
end

module C
  extend B
end
```

**B** can only share its instance methods, not its singleton methods. So to make a method both callable on **B** and shareable to other objects, it must be defined as an instance method and extended into **B** itself:

```
module B
  extend A
  include A

  extend self

  def buzz
    true
  end
end

module C
  extend B
end
```

---

There was a fair amount of trial and error in putting this all together. Is it an accurate way of viewing what's going on?

Comment: Is there any way to simplify your question? Even if you were to put it in a gist with the different scenarios debugged out.

Comment: I think you may be confusing the scope change of self when you are extending A inside of B, and then expecting that C will have A. You change scope.  There is also #prepend that can be called. 

To see how these scopes change, call the $ancestors method on your class.

Comment: Sounds like you want to call both mom and daughter by same name :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I mix its bag of tricks into B

This phrase and your question in general made me believe there is a little misunderstanding in concept of `include`/`extend` thing. I apologize in advance, because I don't fully understand the question.

For example you have such module:

```
module A
  def a
    puts "a"
  end

  def self.b
    puts "b"
  end
end
```

As you see there are 2 types of methods:

- **singleton_methods**
- **instance_methods**

Here is the easiest way to show that they actually differ:

```
A.singleton_methods
=> [:b]
A.instance_methods
=> [:a]
A.a
NoMethodError: undefined method `a' for A:Module
A.b
b
=> nil
```

If you do `include A` simplistically you are adding its **instance** methods to the current module **instance** methods. When you do `extend A` simplistically you are adding its **instance** methods to the current module **singleton** methods.

```
module B
  include A
end

module C
  extend A
end

B.instance_methods
=> [:a]
B.singleton_methods
=> []
C.instance_methods
=> []
C.singleton_methods
=> [:a]
```

One more thing to say is that you could `extend self` but not `include self` as that doesn't make any sense and also will raise an exception.

```
module D
  extend self

  def a
    puts "a"
  end

  def self.b
    puts "b"
  end
end

D.singleton_methods
=> [:b, :a]
D.instance_methods
=> [:a]
D.a
a #no error there because we have such singleton method
=> nil
```

I guess these things could help you. There are a lot of questions about `extend`/`include` on StackOverflow you may check ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156362/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-ruby)).

Comment: Good answer! One bit got accidentally switched around, I think. One of the statements above should read: "When you do `extend A` simplistically you are adding its **instance** methods to the current module **singleton** methods." (the *"instance"* and "*singleton*" are swapped in the answer)

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work at least for `A` to `B` to `C`

```
module A
  def learned_from_A
    true
  end
end

module B
  prepend A
end

B.learned_from_A  # true

module C
  extend B
end

C.learned_from_A  # true
```