# Ruby on rails, NoMethodError: undefined method `include' for #<#<Class: on all tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

Every test returns an error status with the following message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `include' for #<#<Class:0x60fd1e8>:0x60fd158>
```

Every test of every module fails in this way, however the application runs as expected, without issue

The tests run on one computer, but not the other (Windows 7 and 10, respectively)

Ruby/Rails versions:

```
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]
Rails 4.2.5.1
```

Here is a minimal test that has the issue:

```
test "passes" do
  assert true
end
```

Which returns:

```
SessionControllerTest#test_passes:
NoMethodError: undefined method `include' for #<#<Class:0x45b5c20>:0x45b5a28>
```

Here's a full stack trace:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `include' for #<#<Class:0x5cd6810>:0x5cd6768>
    (erb):7:in `get_binding'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/erb.rb:863:in `eval'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/erb.rb:863:in `result'
    activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/fixture_set/file.rb:42:in `render'
    activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/fixture_set/file.rb:33:in `rows'
    activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/fixture_set/file.rb:24:in `each'
    activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:760:in `block (2 levels) in read_fixture_files'
    activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/fixture_set/file.rb:15:in `open'
    activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:759:in `block in read_fixture_files'
    activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:758:in `each'
    activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:758:in `each_with_object'
    activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:758:in `read_fixture_files'
    activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:590:in `initialize'
    activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:514:in `new'
    activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:514:in `block (2 levels) in create_fixtures'
    activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:511:in `map'
    activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:511:in `block in create_fixtures'
    activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:288:in `disable_referential_integrity'
    activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:508:in `create_fixtures'
    activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:979:in `load_fixtures'
    activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:941:in `setup_fixtures'
    activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:826:in `before_setup'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest/test.rb:106:in `block (3 levels) in run'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest/test.rb:205:in `capture_exceptions'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest/test.rb:105:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest/test.rb:256:in `time_it'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest/test.rb:104:in `block in run'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:331:in `on_signal'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest/test.rb:276:in `with_info_handler'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest/test.rb:103:in `run'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:778:in `run_one_method'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:305:in `run_one_method'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:293:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:292:in `each'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:292:in `block in run'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:331:in `on_signal'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:318:in `with_info_handler'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:291:in `run'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:152:in `block in __run'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:152:in `map'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:152:in `__run'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:129:in `run'
    minitest (5.8.4) lib/minitest.rb:56:in `block in autorun'
```

Comment: Starting rails console or server in this machine doesn't throw any error?

Comment: 'rails server' runs perfectly, and my application works flawlessly

Comment: Do you have the stack trace?

Comment: Added the full trace

Comment: Seems there is some problem in the fixtures. Do you use `include`s in your fixtures? Can you show your fixtures?

Comment: @rscarson can u post yr include method where and how u want to use it ? `include?` ?

Comment: The default ruby method for arrays is `includes?` (with the question mark). It might be that you are missing the question mark somewhere, and the error trace for some reason is not showing you the true source. Try searching all files in your project for the string `includes`

Comment: @rscarson did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: I did not... sorry! Good luck though! Let me know if you do

Comment: What fixed it for me was to use `extend` instead of `include`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5008349/2278235