# rspec test failing - methods.include?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I keep getting this validation error in rspec. Could someone please tell what I'm doing wrong?

```
  1) MyServer uses module
 Failure/Error: expect(MyClient.methods.include?(:connect)).to be true

   expected true
        got false
 # ./spec/myclient_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is my client.rb

```
#!/bin/ruby
require 'socket'

# Simple reuseable socket client

module SocketClient

  def connect(host, port)
    sock = TCPSocket.new(host, port)
    begin
      result = yield sock
    ensure
      sock.close
    end
    result
  rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
  end
end

# Should be able to connect to MyServer
class MyClient
  include SocketClient
end
```

And this is my spec.rb

```
describe 'My server' do

  subject { MyClient.new('localhost', port) }
  let(:port) { 1096 }

  it 'uses module' do
    expect(MyClient.const_defined?(:SocketClient)).to be true
    expect(MyClient.methods.include?(:connect)).to be true
  end
```

I have method `connect` defined in module `SocketClient`. I don't understand why the test keeps failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *class* `MyClient` *doesn't* have a method named `connect`. Try it: `MyClient.connect` will not work.

If you want to check what methods a class defines for its *instances*, use [`instance_methods`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods): `MyClient.instance_methods.include?(:connect)` will be true. [`methods`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-methods) lists the methods an object *itself* responds to, so `MyClient.new(*args).methods.include?(:connect)` would be true.

Really, though, for checking whether a *specific* instance method exists on a class you should use [`method_defined?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-method_defined-3F), and for checking whether an object itself responds to a specific method, you should use [`respond_to?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F):

```
MyClient.method_defined?(:connect)
MyClient.new(*args).respond_to?(:connect)
```

If you really *do* want `MyClient.connect` to work directly, you'd need to use `Object#extend` rather than `Module#include` (see [What is the difference between include and extend in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156362/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-ruby)).