# Undefined module method in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, model

**lib/modules/file_type.rb**

```
module Modules
  module Type
    def friend_name(type:)
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

**app/models/car.rb**

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  include Modules::Type

  def self.to_array
  ...
  name = friend_name(type: 'test')
  ...
  end
end
```

But I am getting this error:

```
undefined method `friend_name'
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: `friend_name` is an instance method of the `Car` class, so `Car.new.friend_name(type: 'test')` works, but `Car.friend_name(type: 'test')` does not.

Comment: What is this code supposed to actually achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `friend_name` is a class method then instead of `include` use `extend` in `Car` model

```
extend Modules::Type
```

More info about difference between `include` and `extend` could be found here -

[What is the difference between include and extend in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156362/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-ruby)

Hope that helps!