# Chef Library Testing with shell_out

Tags: rspec, chef-infra, chefspec

I am writing a custom resource for Chef.  The resource is used for setting sysctl values.  I am basically using the Chef sysctl code and putting some limitations around it.  We don't trust all the users at the company :P

I am trying to put most of the code inside a library helper module so I can test the code easier.  I am not sure if this is best practice.  Let me know if this is bad practice.

Anyway, the issue I am running into is trying to test my library code.  Whenever I try to mock the shell_out command I always get the following error.

```
1) Sysctl::Helpers.set_sysctl_param
     Failure/Error: subject.set_sysctl_param("key1", "value1")

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `shell_out!' for Sysctl::Helpers:Module
```

Library Code

```
module Sysctl
  module Helpers
    include Chef::Mixin::ShellOut
    def self.set_sysctl_param(key, value)
      shell_out!("sysctl -w \"#{key}=#{value}\"")
    end
  end
end
```

Test

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Sysctl::Helpers do
  describe '.set_sysctl_param' do
    let(:shellout) { double(run_command: nil, error!: nil, stdout: '', stderr: double(empty?: true)) }
    before do
      allow(Chef::Mixin::ShellOut).to receive(:new).and_return(shellout)
    end

    it do
      subject.set_sysctl_param("key1", "value1")
      expect(:shellout).to receive(:run_command).with("sysctl -w \"key1=value1\"")
    end
  end
end
```

I appreciate any help or advise you can give me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you *include* a module, you add module methods as instance methods. But you try to access `shell_out` in a class method. You actually need to *extend* your module with Chef::Mixin::ShellOut. This way ShellOut methods will be added as class methods.

```
module Sysctl
  module Helpers
    extend Chef::Mixin::ShellOut  # replace include with extend
    def self.set_sysctl_param(key, value)
      shell_out!("sysctl -w \"#{key}=#{value}\"")
    end
  end
end
```

More on this [What is the difference between include and extend in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/156362/170230)

Comment: Thank you!  This was super helpful.