# ActiveSupport::Concern should be included or extended

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know include is used for access module methods as instance methods while extend is used to access module methods as class methods.

For ActiveSupport::Concern somewhere I see written as,

```
module Test
  include ActiveSupport::Concern
end
```

while at some places written as,

```
module Test
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
end
```

Here my confusion is, ActiveSupport::Concern should be used with include or with extend?

Comment: Could you further specify *"some places"*? Do you mean randomly on the internet or in the official documentation?

Comment: randomly on the net like one here, https://medium.com/@carlescliment/about-rails-concerns-a6b2f1776d7d

Comment: Seems like the author of that article doesn't understand what `ActiveSupport::Concern` is for. The `include ActiveSupport::Concern` effectively does nothing in his examples and can be removed without the code breaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend the module with `ActiveSupport::Concern` in order for the `ActiveSupport::Concern#included` and `#class_methods` methods to work properly.

These two methods are after all pretty much the only reason for its existance.

```
module A
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  # raises ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1))
  included do
    puts "Hello World"
  end
end
```

---

```
module B
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    puts "Hello World"
  end
end

class C
  include B
end
# Outputs Hello World
```

Check out what happens if we inspect the `included` method:

```
module AB
  include ActiveSupport::Concern
  puts method(:included).source_location # nil
end
```

```
module ABC
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  puts method(:included).source_location # .../ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/concern.rb
end
```

When we extend the module with `ActiveSupport::Concern` we are putting it on the ancestors chain of `ABC`, thus the methods of `ActiveSupport::Concern` are available as module methods of `ABC`. This does not happen when you use `include` and the `included` method called is actually [Module#included from the Ruby core](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-included).

Comment: nice example thanks, so we always have to extend right?

Comment: Yes. Since the whole point of ActiveSupport::Concern is to use its methods as module methods. It does not provide any instance methods of use to a class.

Comment: There might be some fringe scenarios where you might want to `include` if you're planning on doing some meta programming yourself. However 99.99% of the time `extend` is the way to go.

Comment: @3limin4t0r If you're doing additional meta programming I would'nt use ActiveSupport::Concern in the first place as its functionality is actually pretty simple to emalute in whatever crazy shenanigans you're up to with less added complixity. But thats just my 2c.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `extend ActiveSupport::Concern`, like shown in the examples in the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).

> By using `ActiveSupport::Concern` the above module could instead be
>   written as:
>
> ```
> require 'active_support/concern'
>
> module M
>   extend ActiveSupport::Concern
>
>   included do
>     scope :disabled, -> { where(disabled: true) }
>   end
>
>   class_methods do
>     ...
>   end
> end
> ```

The reason for using `extend` is to make the methods defined in `ActiveSupport::Concern` available in module context. This allows you to use the methods `included` and `class_methods` within the module.

When using `include` those methods would not be available within the module and instead be available on instances of a class that includes `M`.

If you want to know the difference between the two I suggest taking a look at [What is the difference between include and extend in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/156362/3982562)

Comment: I know the include vs extend diff, my confusion is with ActiveSupport::Concern.
I checked this API doc also but it's not clear. Can you elaborate why extend and not include for ActiveSupport::Concern

Comment: @RajKumarSharma I've updated the answer with a small explanation.