# Undefined Method on Include Module Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this class `Callback` to act as custom `attr_accessor`

```ruby
module Callback
  def add_callback(name)
    define_method(name) do
      instance_variable_get("@#{name.to_s}")
    end

    define_method("#{name.to_s}=") do |value|
      instance_variable_set("@#{name.to_s}", value)
    end
  end
end
```

I do include the class into my main class

```ruby
require_relative "./callback"
class TaskManager
  include Callback
  add_callback :on_start, :on_finished, :on_error

  def initialize; end
end
```

But when I require it in irb I got undefined method error

```
require "./task_manager.rb"
irb(main):003:0> require "./task_manager.rb"
/Users/task_manager.rb:9:in `<class:TaskManager>': undefined method `add_callback' for TaskManager:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Both file already in same folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolved the issue like below

```
module Callback
  def add_callback(*attr_names)
    attr_names.each do |name|  
        define_method(name) do
          instance_variable_get("@#{name.to_s}")
        end
    
        define_method("#{name.to_s}=") do |value|
          instance_variable_set("@#{name.to_s}", value)
        end
    end
  end
end
class TaskManager
  extend Callback
  add_callback :on_start, :on_finished, :on_error

  def initialize; end
end
```

When you `include` a module into a class, the module methods are imported as instance methods.

However, when you `extend` a module into a class, the module methods are imported as class methods.

Also please have a look blow answer for more detail

[What is the difference between include and extend in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156362/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-ruby)

Need to use variable number of arguments like below

```
def add_callback(*attr_names); end
```

because of calling of method use multiple arguments

```
  add_callback :on_start, :on_finished, :on_error
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use getter and setter explicitly, there is [`attr_accessor`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) in Ruby

If your `initialize` is empty you can omit it

```rb
module Callback
  def add_callback(*attr_names)
    attr_accessor(*attr_names)
  end
end

class TaskManager
  extend Callback
  add_callback :on_start, :on_finished, :on_error
end
```

```
task_manager = TaskManager.new
task_manager.on_start = 10
task_manager.on_start # => 10
```

BTW you also don't need to use `to_s` for object in string interpolation (it will be applied automatically) in your `"@#{name.to_s}"`

Comment: thanks @mechanicov, this give me new idea to do in my class

Comment: The `instance_eval` call isn't needed, you can just invoke `attr_accessor(attr_name)`. And instead of a loop you could pass the arguments at once via `attr_accessor(*attr_names)`.