# Ruby: Are these two methods of mixing-in module methods equivalent?

Tags: ruby

I have a module and a class.

```rb
module Dog
  def speak
    "woof"
  end
end

class Daschund; end
```

I create two separate instances of the class.

```rb
sausage = Daschund.new
saveloy = Daschund.new
```

If I want to add `Dog#woof` as an instance method of my two new objects, I can do it in two ways:

```rb
class << sausage
  include Dog
end
```

```
> sausage.speak
=> "woof"
```

```rb
saveloy.extend Dog
```

```rb
> saveloy.speak
=> "woof"
```

Are the two methods equivalent? I know the first adds the module's method to the object's meta-class. Does `object#extend` do the same thing? Or is it doing something slightly different? Is there any way to prove this?

Comment: `extend` is the more Ruby way, although arbitrarily extending individual objects is something you may want to avoid. Why can't you inherit a subclass and have `Dog` as a parent? Composition is a valid way of solving this, but a clear inheritance path is always good to have.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156362/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-ruby), though it's from ten years ago and Ruby has evolved quite a bit, so I'm hesitant to mark as dup.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo definitely related and worth reading, but I think it's not a dup. This question here is specifically about extending an object vs. including into its singleton class, whereas the other question calls `include` and `extend` within a class, asking for their differences in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs for [Object](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Object.html#class-Object-label-Querying), extending an object with a module means including that module to the object's singleton class:

> `extend`: Includes the given modules in the singleton class of `self`.

Inspecting the [`ancestors`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Module.html#method-i-ancestors) of both objects' singleton classes confirms this:

```
sausage.singleton_class.ancestors
#=> [#<Class:#<Daschund:0x00007fa6af92e868>>, Dog, Daschund, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

saveloy.singleton_class.ancestors
#=> [#<Class:#<Daschund:0x00007fa6af92e778>>, Dog, Daschund, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

The actual implementation details of course depend on the Ruby implementation and version you are using. For MRI/YARV, you have [`rb_extend_object`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_0/eval.c#L1688-L1692) defined as:

```c
void
rb_extend_object(VALUE obj, VALUE module)
{
    rb_include_module(rb_singleton_class(obj), module);
}
```

Comment: For me, `sausage.singleton_class.constants` returns `[]`. And `sausage.singleton_class.methods.include? :speak` returns `false`.

Comment: @user3574603 sorry, that was a copy-and-paste typo, it's `ancestors` of course, not `constants` :)